# I have a question about the order of "as much as" with lengthy phrase

Tags: grammar, word-order

> I don't see as much any big problems in him as some people speak of him

> I don't see as any big problems in him much as some people speak of him

which sentence is correct I intend to say:

"there might be some problems in him but not much as some people speak of him. they're exaggerating"?

Comment: Do consider that 'much' is used with singular nouns/noun phrases and 'many' with plural ones. In your sentence, 'big problems' is plural so your question should refer to 'many'.

Comment: @JMB I used much because I wanted to focus on degree not numbers

Comment: You have to say "as many problems" or "as much of a problem" (and please note that 'I' is always capitalised).

Comment: @KateBunting I do know that sorry if my wording annoyed you. so is it just ungrammatical if I use "as much as" in similar way as "to the extent that"? I'm not talking about the number of problems but how people speak of him.

Comment: Neither of your example sentences is grammatical. You could say _I don't see as many big problems with him as some people say there are_ or _I don't see that there's as much of a problem as some people say [there is]_. If you have used an expression meaning 'not as much' in the first half of the sentence, you don't need to repeat 'as much' in the second half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could think of is:

> I don't see any big problems in him, not as much as some people do.

BUT, this sentence is contradictory because of the use of ANY combined with NOT AS MUCH AS. If you don't see any problems, then this is an absolute negation (*I see **NO** problem in him*) and this cannot have degrees. Therefore, either "any" or "not as much as some people do" should be omitted.

The way you formulated the meaning you wish to convey would urge me to express it like this

> I don't see big problems in him, at least not as much as some people do.

Comment: Thank you so much now I understand its concept but just to make it clear can I question one more thing? if "any" is there for emphasis and "much" solely for talking about the way/how the people speak of him, could it be still contradictory?

Comment: This is not how it would be commonly expressed. Maybe: "I don't see any big problems in him. I don't think he is as problematic/dangerous as some people say he is."

Comment: I really appreciate it. I should've asked here first I was holding onto it for 30~40 mins. thank you again!!